# Problems with zend and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, shared-hosting

I'm trying to make a Zend application on a shared webhost, I have no access to php.ini or anything.

Zend has been set up and working for the index controller / view.
But when I try to access another controller / view by let's say "mysite.com/About" I get this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /home/vhosting/g/vhostxx/domains/mysite.com/htdocs/projectname/public/index.php was not found on this server.
```

My folder structure looks like this one here: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend+Framework+Default+Project+Structure+-+Wil+Sinclair (see point 9)

The .htaccess in the root (/home/vhosting/g/vhostxx/domains/mysite.com/htdocs/projectname) looks like this:

```
php_value include_path "/domains/mysite.com/htdocs/www/library"

Options All -Indexes

php_flag display_errors on

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

And the .htaccess in the public folder looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This is the index.php in the public folder:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') :  'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
APPLICATION_ENV,
APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
        ->run();
```

And the (empty) bootstrap in the application folder:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

}
```

The controller I'm trying to access is: projectname/application/controllers/AboutController.php
Which should be accessable via mysite.com/About but instead I recieve the message stated earlier.

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing. Can anyone tell me how to solve this or how to debug this?

On a sidenote: My host automaticly translates

```
mysite.com/htdocs/projectname/
```

into

```
mysite.com/htdocs/www/
```

on ftp, not sure if that is a problem or happens when accessing it via http

Comment: Does `/about` exist as a directory on your server?  It needs to otherwise you will redirect that to `/index.php` which is what is happening?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn the controller is in projectname/application/controllers/AboutController.php and the view in projectname/application/views/scripts/about/index.phtml the same setup for the index controller is working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your public folder, change:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

to include a leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Apache guesses what a rewrite rule's target is, whether it's URI-path for file-path, and it looks like it is incorrectly guessing that it's a file path. You could alternatively add a base to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: @JonLin I'm curious to understand how this fixed the problem.  I'm confused over the error message `projectname/public/index.php was not found on this server`, which I thought should exist.  Also, with the fix in place does the rewritten request become `projectname/public//index.php`, now with two slashes?  TIA, John

Comment: @HeatfanJohn When the error message reported to the browser is `The requested URL /home/vhosting/g/vhostxx/domains/mysite.com/htdocs/projectname/public/index.php was not found on this server.`, which exposes the filesystem path all the way up to the document root, it indicates apache is mixing up file-paths vs URI-paths. Adding the `/` in front (or the rewrite base) tells apache that this is a URI-path